# Why React Native Android app is running very slow on debug mode?

Tags: javascript, performance, react-native

I am working on react native application, It's running very slow on debug mode. It takes huge time to load and hangs multiple times.

I am running my app on the following devices::

> - Redmi Note 4
> - & Oppo F1s

And using RN Version: 0.61.4

Please suggest me how can I run app fast on debug mode? and what other devices I can use for this?

Comment: you are taking about debug build application or when you are using remote debugger in browser ???

Comment: debug mode means debug apk ?

Comment: No, I am talking about app debugging in development mode

Comment: share your package.json file @ArchanaSharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using remote debugging the app is expected to run slower.

1) remove unwanted consoles

2) off debug remotely and only use terminal to show output

3) animation are always slow on debeg mode

4) check if there are warnings in console when you run the project. resolve these warnings.

if still your app is slow on debug mode then install new application and compare its speed with you app. if it is showing too much difference then your app have some issue in its code

Comment: Please tell me the devices works best for development testing.

Answer (score 1):

BASIC STEP- Try to avoid chrome debugger, it may slow down your app.

Comment: Can you tell me then what can I use to check my console outputs instead of chrome debugger?

Comment: Use react-native log-android and react-native log-ios in your terminal.